# Filepicker pick and convert (Filepicker.io) in one step with only one image

Tags: filepicker.io

Is there a possibility to resize the image on pick?

At the moment I first make a pick and than run the convert function in callback. The problem is that there are now two files, but I only need the resized one. Must the other file deleted manually or is there any other possibility?

It is written in coffee:

```
    filepicker.pick 
        mimetypes: [
            'image/*', 'text/plain'
        ]
        services: [
            'COMPUTER',
            'FACEBOOK',
            'PICASA',
            'DROPBOX',
            'INSTAGRAM'
        ]
        ( FPFile ) =>
            filepicker.convert FPFILE, {width: 32}, (medfile)->
                  console.log medfile
                  return
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no capability to combine the pick and convert capabilities into a single step, but you may want to look at doing dynamic conversions via the /convert REST endpoint. See more information at https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#fpurl-images